# Street names and custom layers not showing using the iOS SDK

Tags: ios, sdk, label, layer

I have a situation where any/all street names, map named locations and all custom layers are not showing up on my applications use of the iOS SDK (using the "latest" version" in studio).

I have created just a base map using both the Streets and Navigation template with the same result.   This is only effecting one of my customers however they are using the same version of our iOS application as other customers that do not have this issue.

Other than trying to create a new style from a template, where can I troubleshoot this?

Rich

Create new style and display all contents of it on a iOS application.